# Setting Kafka Producer Properties in REST Proxy

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Hi does anyone have an example of having a call to Kafka REST Proxy to POST a message to topic, and to change a producer property as well.  I want to change max.request.size to like 5 MB. I would like to do it on a per call basis and not have to modify the .properties file ( I know that doesn't make total sense because its supposed to be per topic, but I have a lot of topics).  I think it must be pretty simple but I just can't find an example on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/api.html#api-v2) I don't believe this is possible per-request.

Maybe you could just run an additional instance of the REST proxy to serve this particular use-case?

Comment: I wanted something quick and dirty and spinning up another proxy and configuring it not to conflict with the other one in my sandbox and then writing a script to distribute the load is not what i had in mind.  But it does solve the problem and I didnt think of it before u said it, so thats def worth an upvote